# If Cell in Range Contains Value Then Insert file path in Cell to the left

Tags: vba, excel

The title above should explain what I am trying to succeed here. Can anyone help me?

```
Dim csv_ap As String
Dim path_report As String

Sheets("Mail Report").Activate
csv_ap = Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value

If csv_ap = "NO" Then
path_report = MAIN_PATH & "For Resolution\" & Format(today, "dd_mm_yy") & "manual_handling_" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Value

End If

Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = path_report
```

I have altered the code above using the information people supplied me in the comments below. I am now getting the problem that the last "NO" processed will paste its path location in Range(B1) where it replaces the header. Can anyone see where another problem lies?

```
Dim csv_ap As String
Dim path_report As String

Sheets("Mail Report").Activate
csv_ap = Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Value

If csv_ap = "NO" Then
path_report = MAIN_PATH & "For Resolution\" & Format(today, "dd_mm_yy") & "manual_handling_" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Value

Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Value = path_report

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a working code from another post which works perfectly:

```
Dim csv_ap As Range
Dim path_report As String

Sheets("Mail Report").Activate
set csv_ap = Range("C65000").End(xlUp)

If csv_ap.Value = "NO" Then
path_report = MAIN_PATH & "For Resolution\" & Format(today, "dd_mm_yy") & "manual_handling_" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Value

csv_ap.Offset(0, -1) = path_report

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line `csv_ap = Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value`

From looking at it. You are going to `C65000` then going up until there is a value. But then you are adding one to it. So if cell that has the last value in was `C3` it would go to `C4` Which would be empty. And so `csv_app` would always be `vbnullstring` or `""` so change the line to be

`csv_ap = Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Value`

So from this code you are trying to find the last value in `C` and then put the value in the `B` column with the newest blank cell.

Comment: After taking your advice it will now replace the header(B1) by the latest "NO" path location. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The offset is your problem it's always going to return a blank cell:  I came up with this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim csv_ap As String
    Dim path_report As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Const MAIN_PATH As String = "FOR_TESTING_ONLY"

    Set ws = Sheets("Mail Report")

    csv_ap = ws.Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Value 'remove offset, you're always going to get a blank cell with it.

    If csv_ap = "NO" Then
        path_report = MAIN_PATH & "For Resolution\" & Format(Date, "dd_mm_yy") & "manual_handling_" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Value
        'changed today to date, Excel 2007 doesn't have a today function for me to test with
        Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Value = path_report ' removed offset to match csv_ap
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: beat you to it by a minute =]

Comment: Using your code above I altered mine, but it will now replace the header(B1) by the latest "NO" path location. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I accidently edited your answer instead of my question...sorry!